# NSOrderedSame not YES even though values in NSLog are equal

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsstringencoding

I have a simple but strange problem. I compare to strings, (taken from different xmls), to find out if they match. If i trace the variables via NSLog, they LOOK the same, but obviously are not. So i guess it's got to do something with its encodings, but i don't know what. Anyone help?

I found out that the strings are not of the same length, but i can't find whitespaces:

Code:

```
NSString* value1 = [mymovieId stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSString* value2 = [movieId stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@ == %@", mymovieId, movieId);
NSLog(@"%i / %i", value1.length, value2.length);

if ([value1 compare:value2] == NSOrderedSame) {
    NSLog(@"YES!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"NO!");
}
```

result:

```
2012-01-17 20:40:06.044 Appname[6307:f803] 75175343 == 75175343
2012-01-17 20:40:06.044 Appname[6307:f803] 9 / 8
2012-01-17 20:40:06.045 Appname[6307:f803] NO!
```

Certainly this problem onyl exists due to my rawdata, but I can't upload my whole project here, so i hope someone knows an answer anyway.

Thanx Wolfgang

Comment: What are the types of your variables? It could be a signed/unsigned problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging the strings as data:

```
NSLog(@"mymovieId: %@", [mymovieId dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"movieId: %@", [movieId dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]);
```

That will print hex dumps of the strings, making it possible to see unprintable characters.

From your comment it looks like one of your strings starts with a newline.  Try this:

```
movieId = [movieId stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
mymovieId = [mymovieId stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed the hexvalues differ. But it's not about whitespaces (see edited question above). the hexvalues are:

    mymovieId: <fffe0a00 39003000 30003400 35003300 35003100>
    movieId:   <fffe3700 35003100 37003500 33003400 3300>

So what can i do?

Comment: Because even though they are different by data, they need to be equal by logic.

Comment: The first string is "\n90045351" and the second string is "75175343".  So you printed two completely different strings, and the first string starts with a newline character.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up rows in my log :/ But your code does it! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

try using

[`[NSString compare: options: range:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare%3aoptions%3arange%3a)

(i.e. include a range of one of the strings).

My guess is that you have some white space at the end of your string (coming from one of the XML results).  Checking the length of those two strings will show you for certain.

Comment: the length is not equal, you are right! but it's not about whitespaces, see edited question above

Comment: Maybe it's not white space... maybe it's a CR or LF.  Who knows.  The point is, find the shorter string of the two and then compare the string based on the length (or "range") of the shorter string (and then use that shorter string going forward, which would clip off whatever the offending non-numerical characters are).